# Owl Carousel problems (autoplay + responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using owlcarousel on my website, but I have a few problems. For one, the responsiveness isn't working properly. And for two, the carousel won't autoplay. You can see the issue [here](http://attivare.dev.sevendays.be).

Here's my code:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    center: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive:{
      0:{
          items: 1 
      },
      600:{
          items: 1
      },
      1200:{
          items: 1
      }
  }
});
```

Update: I managed to fix the responsive issues by adding:

```
itemsDesktop: [1200, 1],
itemsTablet: [980, 1],
itemsMobile: [700, 1]
```

to the options.

Still, the autoplay isn't working.

Comment: `autoplaySpeed: 5000` would make your slider really slow, consider removing this as you are using quite large size images, also if you are displaying one item you don't need `responsive` Object. There is nothing wrong with your owl carousel code, might be something else causing the problem you are facing.

Comment: You see what happens when the screen gets smaller though? That's why I added the responsive object. The responsive options don't seem to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution :

```
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            item:3,
            singleItem: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items: 1,
                    dots: false
                },
                600:{
                    items: 2,
                    dots: false
                },
                1200:{
                    items: 3
                }
            }
        });
```